# DAX conditional sum

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to construct a DAX measure which returns sum of either A or B. The logic is take B if A is empty. So expected results looks like this:

```
+---+---+----------+
| A | B | Expected |
+---+---+----------+
| 1 |   |        1 |
| 1 |   |        1 |
|   | 2 |        2 |
| 1 | 2 |        1 |
|   | 2 |        2 |
+---+---+----------+
| 3 | 6 |        7 |
+---+---+----------+
```

When I use measure:

```
Measure = IF(ISBLANK([SUM(tab[A])]), SUM(tab[B]), SUM(tab[A]))
```

I get 3 for total which is logical but not what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a `SUMX` iterator in this case.

```
Measure = SUMX ( tab, IF ( ISBLANK ( tab[A] ), tab[B], tab[A] ) )
```

You might be able to do the following as well:

```
Measure = 
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( tab[A] ) ) +
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( tab[B] ),
        FILTER ( tab, ISBLANK( tab[A] ) )
    )
```

Comment: I cannot get it to work. A is a product and B is a Brand, they have different generalities. So in a bridge table Brand exists for both A and B. But product is only for A. I think that your second measure is closer to my expected results however it keeps summing A + B.

Comment: I've edited it a bit but I'm shooting in the dark without seeing the tables and relationships.

Comment: I asked it as a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57713806/dax-conditional-sum-of-two-columns-with-different-granularity Don't shoot in the dark:-)