# DAX conditional sum of two columns with different granularity

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is follow up question of the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57693531/1903793). However this time two columns have different granularity and are located in different tables. So simple `SUMX` solution proposed earlier is not applicable. I attach [SumDifferntGranularity.pbix](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1wfafotiGSGKP9AQkJtBCNpAK_VU1GXke&export=download) file.

How to construct a DAX measure which returns sum of either BudgetProduct (if possible) or BudgetBrand. The logic is take Brand if Product is empty. So expected results looks like this:

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Manager | BudgetBrand | BudgetProduct | Expected result |
+---------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Alice   |          16 |            15 |              15 |
| John    |           7 |               |               7 |
| Martha  |          21 |            21 |              21 |
| Zadar   |          11 |               |              11 |
+---------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Total   |          55 |            36 |              54 |
+---------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

In this example, all Managers have budget defined on Brand, but some Managers (Alice and Martha) have budget defined on Products. How to construct a measure which will take budget defined on products, if possible, but if not possible then it will take the budget defined on Brands.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
Expected Result =
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Unique_Manager,
        Unique_Manager[Manager],
        "Budget_Brand", SUM ( Budget_Brand[BudgetBrand] ),
        "Budget_Product", SUM ( Budget_Product[BudgetProduct] )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        Summary,
        IF ( ISBLANK ( [Budget_Product] ), [Budget_Brand], [Budget_Product] )
    )
```

This groups by `Manager` and calculates a summary table with the sum for `BudgetBrand` and `BudgetProduct` for each and the iterates through this summary table with `SUMX` using the logic specified.

---

Here's a bit cleaner implementation

```
Expected Result =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( Unique_Manager[Manager] ),
    VAR SumBrand = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Budget_Brand[BudgetBrand] ) )
    VAR SumProduct = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Budget_Product[BudgetProduct] ) )
    RETURN
        IF ( ISBLANK ( SumProduct ), SumBrand, SumProduct )
)
```

I this one, we don't need a calculated table to iterate over. Instead, we iterated over all the distinct values of `Manager` in the local filter context and sum `BudgetBrand` and `BudgetProduct` within that context. Note that I've wrapped the sums in `CALCULATE`. This is done to perform the context transition from the row context inside `SUMX` (the particular `Manager`) to having that `Manager` as a filter context on `BudgetBrand` and `BudgetProduct`. Storing these sums as variables makes for a more readable `IF` line and only requres `SumProduct` to be computed once instead of twice.

Comment: Thank you:-) So I see that the rule is to build a single table first, and then follow the approach you suggested in initial question. However, if I'd like to keep the option of using slicers for Products (or whatever other dimensions) then I should build a Cartesian product of all these dimensions for the first argument of SUMX. If so, how could such a Cartesian product be applied to both your approaches? I mean `CROSSJOIN(VALUES(Unique_Manager[Manager]), VALUES(Unique_Brand[Brand]), VALUES(Unique_Product[Product]))`

Comment: I don't think you'd need to do that. Since we haven't removed any filter contexts with an `ALL()` type of function, these should still follow any filtering from slicers.

Comment: Please add a slicer for Product and select Apple only. I would expect results only for Alice and Martha since only they have budget defined on products, and only they have apples. But instead it shrinks Alice and Martha to apples but also returns total budget for other managers.

Comment: Why do you expect to see Jonn and Zadar when you haven't selected a product then? It seems like you are expecting different logic to apply when using a slicer.

Comment: On the contrary, when I select apples in the slicer then I expect to see nothing for John or Zadar. But the measure calculates total brand for John or Zadar. No matter what product you choose, you will always get 7 for John and 11 for Zadar.

Comment: I said "when you *haven't* selected a specific product". This is equivalent to selecting all products, where you seem to want to eliminate people that don't have those products, in which case John and Zadar would be blank. Unless your logic is different for the total and with specific product(s) selected, John and Zadar are either always included or always excluded.