# DAX Difference between naked SUM and sum wrapped in CALCULATE

Tags: powerbi, dax

What is the difference between naked `SUM` and sum wrapped in `CALCULATE`?

```
Measure1 = SUM( tab[col1]) )
Measure2 = CALCULATE ( SUM( tab[col1]) ) )
```

**Update.**

I was given an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57713934/1903793) to other SO question, which uses wrapped calculate. The author of the question gave explanation to it which I still do not understand. Here is the measure the author proposed:

```
Expected Result =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( Unique_Manager[Manager] ),
    VAR SumBrand = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Budget_Brand[BudgetBrand] ) )
    VAR SumProduct = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Budget_Product[BudgetProduct] ) )
    RETURN
        IF ( ISBLANK ( SumProduct ), SumBrand, SumProduct )
)
```

And the explanation:

> (...) Note that I've wrapped the sums in CALCULATE. This is done to
>   perform the context transition from the row context inside SUMX (the
>   particular Manager) to having that Manager as a filter context on
>   BudgetBrand and BudgetProduct. Storing these sums as variables makes
>   for a more readable IF line and only requres SumProduct to be computed
>   once instead of twice.

I know what is filter context. But I do not understand what is *context transition*. Are there any other *transitions*?

Comment: No difference. Measures already have an implicit CALCULATE

Comment: @GregGalloway See my edit please.

Comment: CALCULATE is necessary there because of the SUMX. If the CALCULATE was at the top level then it would be unnecessary since a measure has an implicit CALCULATE around it.

Comment: @GregGalloway No, it is not necessary. You may throw away the CALCULATE wrap and it will work anyway. It works with and without CALCULATE.

Comment: Hopefully the other answers clarified this for you, but in your Expected Result measure if you remove the CALCULATE the result will be different. See this sample PBIX file here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoL33J0T45AcgZQ8Z6cZI1Zf9fqaWA?e=2hOlB7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer addresses the use of `CALCULATE` generally and covers the topics of filter context, row context, and context transition.

As defined in the original question, [Measure1] and [Measure2] would behave identically, per the original response below. See the edit to this answer for a fuller treatment of `CALCULATE`.

In general, if you're looking at an expression in row context, you'll use `CALCULATE` with a single argument to cause a context transition (row context -> filter context).

A common beginner mistake I see is redundant/unnecessary `CALCULATE`s in expressions. `CALCULATE` should be used only when you want to affect the filter context of the first argument. This takes two general forms:

1. You want to use args 2-N to add, remove, or change filter context.
2. You want to transition row context to filter context.

The two may come together.

A corollary to the above is that you should never use `CALCULATE` with one arg unless the call-site is in a row context.

**Edit**: based on comments and updated question

It seems there's some confusion in this question. So I'll clear that up first, before getting into context transition.

**Note:** wherever I refer to `CALCULATE` below, you can also read `CALCULATETABLE`, which behaves nearly identically. The first is for scalar expressions and the second is for table expressions.

A measure is **not just** a named DAX expression. A measure is a named DAX expression **with an implicit `CALCULATE` wrapped around it**. Thus, if you want to replace a reference to a measure with its expression, you don't just do a simple text replacement, you would write `CALCULATE ( <measure body> )`.

I try not to guess at different meanings of a question if the form it is asked in is self-consistent. I believe you meant to ask:

> What is the difference between the following DAX expressions:
>
> `SUM ( 'tab'[col1] )`
>
> and
>
> `CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'tab'[col1] ) )`

This is materially different than the question you asked, because you were asking about two fully defined measures, not two snippets of DAX. The measures will behave identically, because their expansions are logically equivalent:

```
//Measure 1 definition:
Measure1 = SUM ( 'tab'[col1] )

// Measure 1 expands to the following, and you would use this if you were
// replacing a reference with code:
//Expansion1:
CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'tab'[col1] ) )
```

```
//Measure2 definition and expansion:
Measure2 = CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'tab'[col1] ) )

//Expansion2:
CALCULATE ( CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'tab'[col1] ) ) )
```

So, your measures are semantically (though not textually) identical. Both perform as a `SUM` wrapped in a `CALCULATE`. [Measure2] just happens to have an extra `CALCULATE` upon expansion.

So what does `CALCULATE` do? A lot. For reference, when I give DAX trainings, `CALCULATE` and filter and row context are a multi-hour segment.

`CALCULATE` does the following.

1. Performs context transition. It creates a new filter context within which to evaluate its first argument expression. This new filter context consists of the following (merged into a single filter context):

   a. Whatever external filter context exists at the call-site of `CALCULATE`

   b. Whatever row context exists at the call-site of `CALCULATE`
2. Evaluates args 2-N (known as setfilters) to modify (add to, remove from, or modify existing) the filter context from step(1), and finally
3. Evaluates the expression in arg1 in the new filter context determined by steps (1) and (2).

So, this begs a couple questions, namely:

1. What is a filter context?
2. What is a row context?
3. What does it mean to transform a row context into a filter context?

So, first, filter context. Filter context comes from several DAX functions, including `CALCULATE`, `CALCULATETABLE`, `SUMMARIZE`, `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS`, and `GROUPBY`. This list is not intended to be exhaustive, but does cover some very common functions.

Whenever you interact with a Tabular model in a reporting tool, e.g. Excel pivot tables or Power BI reports, your actions in the GUI generate queries which are used to populate any visual. From the perspective of these (and other) reporting tools, filter context comes from:

- Row/Column/Axis labels (don't confuse a pivot table row for contributing row context - it does not)
- Pivot table filters
- Slicers
- Other visuals' selections as cross-filtering
- Visual/Page/Report/Drill-through/Tooltip filters

You can think of filter context as a set of 'Table'[Column]->values maps. Whatever literal values are selected, or meet a selection criteria become the filter context.

For example, let's consider a matrix visual with 'Calendar'[Year] on rows, 'Calendar'[MonthName] on columns, a slicer of 'Product'[Category]="Clothing", and a page level filter of 'Calendar'[Year]>2015. We'll look at the filter context for a measure, [M], being evaluated in the matrix on the third row and fourth column (April, 2018)

```
Filter Context:
'Calendar'[Year]=2018
'Calendar'[Year]>2015
    => 'Calendar'[Year] IN {2016, 2017, 2018, ..., N} // for whatever years exist in the calendar
'Calendar'[Month]="April"
'Product'[Category]="Clothing"
```

Each cell of the matrix would have its own filter context based on the intersection of year and month, but the rest would remain the same. For the grand total row at the bottom, the filter context would have no specific year from the matrix, but would still be affected by the page level filter. For the grand total column at the right, there would be no month context, but there would be a specific year in context. For the grant total cell at the bottom right of the matrix, the only filters would be:

```
'Product'[Category]="Clothing"
'Calendar'[Year]>2015 //from the page-level
```

In summary, filter context is pretty much aligned with what you probably understood it as. I have found that for most people, filter context on its own makes sense.

Now for row context. Row context exists whenever we are iterating a table. You will find a row context in two places:

1. When adding a calculated column to a table
2. In an iterator function, e.g.:

   - -X functions (`SUMX`, `AVERAGEX`, etc...)
   - `FILTER`
   - `ADDCOLUMNS`

Whenever we talk about row context, we're talking about iteration. You can think of a for-loop like:

```
//pseudocode
for row in table:
    <expression>
```

You might also consider row context as analogous to a SQL cursor, iterating the rows of a table. It would be largely equivalent to a fast-forward, read-only cursor.

We consider one row at a time. The row context consists of the set of literal values in the columns of the table being iterated.

Thus, given a table, 'T' with columns (Id, Amount, Date), the row context in `SUMX ( 'T', <expression )` consists of the specific values of 'T'[Id], 'T'[Amount], and 'T'[Date]. You can refer to any of these values by column reference in `<expression>`. You can also use a table-valued function as the first argument to an iterator, e.g. `SUMX ( VALUES ( 'T'[Date] ), <expression> )`. In this case, the table we iterate is the return of `VALUES ( 'T'[Date] )`, which is the set of unique values in the 'T'[Date] column. In this case, the row context consists only of a value from 'T'[Date] - the rest of 'T' is not in the row context.

Note: when we are in a row context we can refer to a column by name without aggregating it - this is not valid anywhere in DAX except in a row context.

Note2: Basic aggregation functions such as `SUM` or `COUNTROWS` have no interaction with row context. So, for the table and expressions below we will see results that likely have no meaning:

```
//Table, 'T' with schema as above
{
  (1, 10, 2019-02-01),
  (2, 20, 2019-02-01),
  (3, 30, 2019-03-01),
  (4, 40, 2019-03-02)
}

//Add calculated column to 'T'
C = SUM ( 'T'[Amount] )
// Result would be 100 on every row - the total of 'T'[Amount]

//Measure on a card visual with no other filters:
M = SUMX ( 'T', SUM ( 'T'[Amount] ) )
// Result would be 400, which is the sum of 'T'[Amount] calculated once per row
// and summed together

//M2 on card with no other filters
M2 = SUMX ( VALUES ( 'T'[Date] ), SUM ( 'T'[Amount] ) )
// Result is 300, which is the sum of 'T'[Amount] calculated once per unique date
// and summed together
```

When we are in a row context and we want the values on the row to contribute to filter context, we can wrap an aggregate in a `CALCULATE` to transform the row context into a filter context. This is referred to as context transition.

```
// Same table as above:
M3 = SUMX ( VALUES ( 'T'[Date] ), CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'T'[Amount] ) ) )
// result on card would be 100, the actual total
```

We can break the calculation down into the following iteration:

```
// Input table would be {2019-03-02, 2019-02-01, 2019-03-01}
//Iteration1:
1. Row context: 'T'[Date]=2019-03-02
2. CALCULATE transitions 'T'[Date] value to Filter context: 'T'[Date]=2019-03-02
3. SUM is evaluated in filter context from step (2)
4. Result of iteration1 = 40

//Iteration2:
1. Row context: 'T'[Date]=2019-02-01
2. CALCULATE transitions 'T'[Date] value to Filter context: 'T'[Date]=2019-02-01
3. SUM is evaluated in filter context from step (2)
4. Result of iteration1 = 30 //note both [Amount]s for 2019-02-01 contribute to this

//Iteration3:
1. Row context: 'T'[Date]=2019-03-01
2. CALCULATE transitions 'T'[Date] value to Filter context: 'T'[Date]=2019-03-01
3. SUM is evaluated in filter context from step (2)
4. Result of iteration1 = 30

// Final result - combine iteration results with sum:
40 + 30 + 30 = 100
```

Note that filter context automatically navigates relationships in the model. Row context consists only of the values in the table being iterated. If you need to navigate a relationship in a row context, you can use `RELATED` or `RELATEDTABLE`, or you can transform the row context into filter context with `CALCULATE` or `CALCULATETABLE`.

So, in your linked example:

```
Expected Result =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( Unique_Manager[Manager] ),
    VAR SumBrand = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Budget_Brand[BudgetBrand] ) )
    VAR SumProduct = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Budget_Product[BudgetProduct] ) )
    RETURN
        IF ( ISBLANK ( SumProduct ), SumBrand, SumProduct )
)
```

`SumBrand` is the sum of 'Budget_Brand'[BudgetBrand] for the 'Unique_Manager'[Manager] in the current row context, i.e. the manager that is the value of current row in iteration. Similarly, `SumProduct` is the sum of 'Budget_Product'[BudgetProduct] for the manager in row context.

You could just as easily define the following:

```
Brand Budget = SUM ( 'Budget_Brand'[BudgetBrand] )

Product Budget = SUM ( 'Budget_Product'[BudgetProduct] )

Expected Result =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( 'Unique_Manager'[Manager] ),
    VAR SumBrand = [Brand Budget]
    VAR SumProduct = [Product Budget]
    RETURN
        IF ( ISBLANK ( SumProduct ), SumBrand, SumProduct )
)
```

I would probably refactor as follows, so that you only calculate the brand budget if you need it:

```
Expected Result =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( 'Unique_Manager'[Manager] ),
    VAR SumProduct = [Product Budget]
    RETURN
        IF ( ISBLANK ( SumProduct ), [Brand Budget], SumProduct )
)
```

With or without that refactoring, though, the version above referencing measures is semantically identical to the version that inlines `CALCULATE ( SUM ( ... ) )`.

This is because, as stated earlier in this edited section, the following two are equivalent:

```
Measure = SUM ( 'tab'[col1] )
```

```
CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'tab'[col1] ) )
```

I hope this is helpful to understand why I was so brave as to answer your original question as I did. As measures, your two expressions are semantically equivalent. As isolated expressions, they are not.

Comment: I would not be so brave to make a categorical statement that they are the same. Please check the measure VAR SumBrand and Alexis explanation in his answer, which is a root of my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57713934/1903793

Comment: Your question defines Measure1 and Measure2. Those two measures will behave identically. The measure you have linked to in your comment uses a `CALCULATE` *within* another expression and is an example of context transition from row context to filter context. I am updating my answer to explain this transition, since you have updated your question to ask what a context transition is.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin, I'm not sure if SO notifies on answer edits, but I've updated this answer based on your clarification.

Comment: I am grateful you took time to give this extensive explanation. I get from it much more than I asked for. Thank you:-)

Comment: Happy to help. Please mark as answered if your question is resolved.

Comment: Consider adding information at the top of the answer that they are not the same. For new bees like me, now your first sentence may be misleading. You have guessed correctly that I mean expressions, not measures.

Comment: Most of the time basic, first off, measure to any sales model was `[SalesMeasure] = CALCULATE (SUM[Sales])` This basic measure is referenced in other measures. Is there any reason for putting this word CALCULATE in this basic, first off measure? Maybe it is superfluous? I can see that this `[SalesMeasure] = SUM[Sales]` works the same. Is there a scenario when it would work different? I can see that Albert and Marco also define basic measure without calculate: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/use-of-rankx-in-power-bi-measures/ scroll down to: `[Sum Value] := SUM ( Test[Value] )`

Answer (score 3):

When `CALCULATE` is used in a row context, transition will occur where each row becomes a filter and the entire table is scanned for each row, using all the columns of the row as a filter. This will have an impact on performance and it could also cause unexpected results if your table has duplicates.

It's possible the two versions you have provided will return the same value. However, if they don't it's probably because of duplicate rows in your table.

You might find [this article](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/) very useful.

Comment: Can you add to one of the measures FILTER so that they wood return the same results?  It would be easier to capture the difference.

Comment: I suppose you could add a filter to the CALCULATE version that doesn’t really filter anything. But you might want to find out why your table has duplicates. That could be problematic.

Comment: This is incorrect. Context transition occurs in all invocations of `CALCULATE`, regardless of how many arguments are used. The setfilter arguments to `CALCULATE` may optionally remove or override the filter context created by the transition.

Comment: @greggyb - I have done further research on this. Your statement is not correct. A context transition does not occur in all invocations of CALCULATE. It only occurs when a row context is present. This can only happen in one of two ways. 1) During the creation of a calculated column; 2) When using an iterator.

Comment: @RandyMinder it seems ambiguous to me whether context transition is skipped outside of row contexts or if it occurs and simply does nothing (because it's operating on an empty row context). Explanations I've seen from Jeffrey Wang, the language author don't appear to be conclusive (these explanations are posted various places online, not from privileged conversations). Semantically it makes no difference.

Comment: @greggyb - It's not ambiguous to Marco Russo. I sent him an email and his response to me was what I mentioned in my previous post.

Comment: Not the first time I've disagreed with Marco on an interpretation and won't be the last. We can get into a correctness measuring contest between semantically equivalent interpretations later if you want. In the meantime I'm editing your answer to remove the statement that context transition only occurs in the one-arg form of `CALCULATE`.

Comment: @greggyb - I have no desire to debate you or anyone else on how DAX works. If Marco Russo or Alberto Ferrari makes a statement about how an aspect of DAX works, I believe them, over anyone else, unless someone on the DAX engineering team states otherwise. And, since Russo and Ferrari are in regular communication with Jeffrey Wang (Principal DAX engineer), I tend to take their teaching as gospel.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you are using the expressions i.e. CALCULATED COLUMN vs MEASURE and in what context. Filter contexts are derived from active filters in your report i.e. SLICERS, CROSS FILTER through visuals themselves and can even be propagated through relationships existing in the model. Used in a calculated column they would yield very different results. See the image below: 
[image]

As you can see Ive provided a very basic data set displaying job titles and their respective salaries. When using the expression without the calculate satatement there is no filter context provided and none would be derived implicitly, thus the column would result in the TOTAL sum for the entire 'Salary' field. When we wrap the same expression in a calculate statement we provide a ROW CONTEXT and get the sum for each ROW within the table. Two very different results.

When used in a measure they would produce identical results. See the image below:
[image]
This is because the SUM() measure would be wrapped with a CALCULATE implicitly and inherit the same functionality as the MEASURE containing the CALCULATE statement. In this case the tree-map is used as a slicer and is providing a filter context to both measure thus producing identical results.

This [ARTICLE](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/row-context-and-filter-context-in-dax/) does a great job of explaining row and filter contexts.

Hope this helps!!