# How to use a measure for each value in a column then sum up the results

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a measure to calculate Man/Operating hours on machines. My measure works great for each individual machine. However, when I want to get the total Man/Operating hours for the entire fleet, the measure doesn't give me the correct result

I believe my problem is that I do not specify machine anywhere in my measures that calculate total labor hours and total hours used. But, I can not figure out how to incorporate that into the DAX.

For Hours Used I have:

```
Hours Used = 
  var __MinVal = MIN(SMU_Usage_Lookup[LTDSMU])
  var __MaxVal = MAX(SMU_Usage_Lookup[LTDSMU])

return
  __MaxVal - __MinVal
```

SMU_Usage_Lookup table looks like this

```
Machine  Date      LTDSMU
A        1/1/2016  1
B        1/1/2016  42
A        1/2/2016  6
B        1/2/2016  53
A        1/3/2016  11
B        1/3/2016  62
C        1/3/2016  513
C        1/4/2016  523
```

When I create a table visual and bring in Machine I get the correct result.

```
Machine  Hours Used  Labor Hours  Man/Op Hours
A        10          1            .10
B        20          5            .25
C        10          2            .20
```

My problem is if I bring in the Total for all machines or just get rid of the Machine column. I get something like this

```
Hours Used  Labor Hours  Man/Op Hours
522         8            .02
```

This is incorrect and I know what is happening. My measure is calculating the hours used as if each machine was just one. It is taking the Min LTDSMU and subtracting it from the Max LTDSMU regardless of machine. What I need it to do instead is add the Hours Used for each machine. So in this case 10 + 20 + 10. I need my result to show

```
Hours Used  Labor Hours  Man/Op Hours
40          8            .2
```

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need more clarification on anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a [`SUMX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax). I would give a definition of the function, but you have done that perfectly with your question title.

```
Hours Used = 
SUMX (
  VALUES ( 'SMU_Usage_Lookup'[Machine] ),
  CALCULATE (
    var __MinVal = MIN(SMU_Usage_Lookup[LTDSMU])
    var __MaxVal = MAX(SMU_Usage_Lookup[LTDSMU])
    return
      __MaxVal - __MinVal
  )
)
```

The VARs are unnecessary here, so you could also refactor and shrink as follows:

```
Hours Used = 
SUMX (
  VALUES ( 'SMU_Usage_Lookup'[Machine] ),
  CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'SMU_Usage_Lookup'[LTDSMU] ) - MIN ( 'SMU_Usage_Lookup'[LTDSMU] ) )
)
```

For additional reading, check out [this question for what `CALCULATE` is doing there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57738792/dax-difference-between-naked-sum-and-sum-wrapped-in-calculate).