# Return Latest Value in Column Based on Date

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I am still very new to Power Pivot & DAX Measures, so a little help would be greatly appreciated here!

I have the below table:

[image]

I am trying to build a DAX measure that will return the latest `[Universe]` value. I have tried a combination of `CALCULATE`, `MAX`, `FILTER`, `EARLIER`, but am struggling to get the desired output, as seen below.

[image]

I don't necessarily want the outputs in a table, but rather in a measure because I want to use it in a calculation.

Note, this is my current attempt:

```
Total Universe:=SUM([Universe])

Last Universe Date:=CALCULATE(MAX([Date]),FILTER(tbData,LASTNONBLANK(tbData[Universe],1)))

Last Universe Value:=CALCULATE([Total Universe],FILTER(tbData,tbData[Date]=[Last Universe Date]))
```

`Last Universe Date` returns the correct date, but `Last Universe Value` returns the Grand Total value.

Any help/ guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Do you want the latest (most recent) for all values in your table, for a given year, for a given date?

Comment: There are several recent questions on very similar challenges. Can you share with us the code you've tried? [Here's a similar question with multiple solutions shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805690/dax-filtering-expressions-last-date-of-every-day/57806859#57806859)

Comment: @RandyMinder I want the most recent `Universe` value when `Universe` is blank, ie. no implicit value. In the above example, for `Channel A` I want `Universe` to return most recent (ie. July value 898), and for `Channel B` I want `Universe` to return most recent (ie. July value 1383)

Comment: @Dean - I'm sorry. I still don't follow you. You don't have any blank Universe values in your example. Or, are the yellow highlighted cells supposed to represent values that are blank, even though they actually contain a value?

Comment: @RandyMinder, there are 2 tables in my post, can you not view both? First table is current table, the second (with yellow) is the desired output. The desired output is what I would like the `Universe` to retrun based on the first table in my post...

Comment: @Dean - Ah, ok. I didn't see the first table until just now.

Comment: @RandyMinder hope that helps give context

Comment: @greggyb I have updated my post with my most current attempt

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty straightforward, unless I'm missing something. In your measure, test if the current Universe value is blank. If it is, find the last Universe value that occurs before this date. Pseudo code might look like this:

```
Universe Value = 
   VAR CurrentDate = MIN('Date')

   RETURN
      IF (ISBLANK(Universe), <Find most recent Universe value less than 'CurrentDate'>, Universe)
```

Finding the last date, if it's based purely on date, could be done with something like this. There are of course other ways you might want to do this. This was my first thought.

```
LastDate = TOPN(
       1,
       FILTER(
          ALL('Date'),
          'Date'[Date] < CurrentDate
          )
       ),
       'Date'[Date],
       DESC
    )
```

I would probably store this in a variable and then retrieve the value associated with this date if the current Universe value is blank.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have established, however, I am uncertain how to get the most recent universe value based on date. It would be purely based on `[Date]`. I was thinking using `FILTER()` but can't seem to get it to work...

Comment: I changed my response to get you what you need, or close to it.

Comment: this is what I have to get the last date: `Last Universe Date:=CALCULATE(MAX([Date]),FILTER(tbData,LASTNONBLANK(tbData[Universe],1)))`, but again, not sure how to retrieve the `Universe` value when `[Date]` is this date..

Comment: The above `LastDate` is returning `Blank`?

Comment: @Dean - I don't think your expression for getting the last date is going to work. Remember your current filter context is going to filter your Date table so that only a single date value exists, the current date.

Comment: @Dean - I'm not able to test this of course because I don't have access to your data. Are you sure the value for 'CurrentDate' contains a non-blank value?

Answer (score 0):

```
Total Universe:= SUM ( 'tbData'[Universe] )
```

```
Last Universe Value:=
VAR MostRecentDate = MAX ( 'tbData'[Date] )
VAR MostRecentNonBlank =
  CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'tbData'[Date] ),
    ALL ( 'tbData'[Date], 'tbData'[Year], 'tbData'[Month] ), // you should really pull this out to
                                                             // a date dimension
    'tbData'[Date] <= MostRecentDate,
    NOT ( ISBLANK ( 'tbData'[Universe] ) )
  )
RETURN
  CALCULATE (
    [Total Universe],
    ALL ( 'tbData'[Date], 'tbData'[Year], 'tbData'[Month] ),
    'tbData'[Date] = MostRecentNonBlank
  )
```

This preserves filter context on 'tbData'[Channel] and 'tbData'[CPT]. If you don't want that, you can throw those into the `ALL`s as well. Your original `FILTER` referencing a measure was performing a context transition from the row context of `FILTER`'s iteration into filter context for the measure evaluation. You can read more about this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57738792/dax-difference-between-naked-sum-and-sum-wrapped-in-calculate/).

Comment: Hi @greggyb, thanks for this. It is returning the Last Universe value, however, I am now struggling with how to return it if `[UNIVERSE]` is blank. I thought it would be trivial in the sense of `IF(ISBLANK([Total Universe]), [Last Universe Value], [Total Universe])` but this is not returning anything in my pivot table..

Comment: Can you share your pivot table layout? A screengrab of the pivot table itself, as well as all the field wells.