# PowerBI/ DAX Condition calculation for dates

Tags: date, datetime, powerbi, dax, business-intelligence

I want to calculate the total number of simultaneous calls (call that had been in the same time), so I should to make a DAX formulas.I have two dates the start & end date, so I should make a counter to calculate for each call the number of simultaneous calls.

[image: IMG 1]

Comment: Can you simplify your sample data. Say you have two columns A and B. What do you want? What condition do you want to check? Say, count cases where column A = B?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin 


I have two columns A & B, and I want to calculate the total number of columns where I have an intersection with A & B ( Calls that was on the same time) I just made this query, but that not's work: 



Simultaneous= CALCULATE( COUNTROWS('DirectRouting calls 19-09-30 203651'); 'DirectRouting calls 19-09-30 203651'[Start time].[Date] <= EARLIER('DirectRouting calls 19-09-30 203651'[Start time].[Date]) && 'DirectRouting calls 19-09-30 203651'[End time].[Date] >= EARLIER('DirectRouting calls 19-09-30 203651'[End time].[Date]) ) –

Comment: Please add a column to your sample data showing which rows "intersect"? What is the relation between Invite time and the names you used in your Dax query? Please edit your answer and paste there your dax code. It would be good if you used short one word column names, and table name too.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin What do you think of this ? 


`New_simultané = 

COUNTROWS( 
    FILTER(
    All('Table1');
        'Table1'[Start time]<= EARLIER('Tabl1'[Start time]) && 
        'Tablea1'[End time]  >= EARLIER('Table1'[End time])
)) `

Comment: I do not know your desired results. It would be best if you could add a column to your sample data with desired results. Please take a look at an example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57693531/1903793